# How do you make a PUT create or update controller handler know whether to create or update?

Tags: java, rest, controller

I have a REST service. There's an endpoint you can hit with a PUT. The Put should update a resource if it exists and create it otherwise. The service is using Java 8 with Spring Boot.

```
/**
* Called by PUT request on HTTP REST endpoint
* Checks if resource exists. If it does, call updateResource, if not call insertResource
**/
insertUpdateHandler
/**
* Inserts record
**/
insertResource
/**
* Checks if record exists, if so update resource
*/
updateResource
```

My problem is that I check twice if the record exists.

I see 5 solutions. But there are probably more:
1. Use different endpoints for create and update but use PUT for both
2. Use PATCH only for updates, PUT for creates
3. Accept that I check for the same record twice
4. Pass the found attribute as an optional parameter. I overloading/optional params would be really messy in Java. Opinions?
5. Put insertOrUpdate in one method. I don't like this as it makes things less scalable. I can't use the same update method for everything.